# Does the magic damage on swords double for a nat 20

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit, damage-types

my barbarian has a frost brand longsword  that does the common 1d8 and 1d6 of cold damage.
Me and my friends are new to d&d so we may be playing it be wrong but for the campaign I'm playing  when someone hits a nat 20 the dice doubles so we would throw 2d8 with a longsword instead of 1d8. If someone else plays like this, would the 1d6 of cold damage also double or just the attack?

Comment: Welcome! I closed this question as a duplicate, as it has been asked before in very similar form. We can reopen it, if that answer does not help you, but in general, I think it explains it well -- extra die you roll as part of the damage are all doubled, including the cold damage in your example.

Comment: Welcome to our stack! If you'd like, you can take the [tour] to learn about us and please also visit the [help] for even more guidance.

Comment: ohh i didn't find that question earlier, thanks!

Comment: Dupes are good things, too! Makes it easier for other folks to ask and find!